# How to use a for loop to divide observations in two columns?

Tags: r

I am working on a MacBook; I am running the latest version of R.

I am new to R.

I have a data frame that I loaded into the variable data.

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76
                     wt  qsec vs am gear
Mazda RX4         2.620 16.46  0  1    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     2.875 17.02  0  1    4
Datsun 710        2.320 18.61  1  1    4
Hornet 4 Drive    3.215 19.44  1  0    3
Hornet Sportabout 3.440 17.02  0  0    3
Valiant           3.460 20.22  1  0    3
                  carb
Mazda RX4            4
Mazda RX4 Wag        4
Datsun 710           1
Hornet 4 Drive       1
Hornet Sportabout    2
Valiant              1
```

I have an assignment that requires the creation of a vector that includes the division of "hp" by "wt." It has to be done using a for loop. This is as far as I have been able to get to.

```
> hp_wt <-c(for(i, data) {hp/wt})
Error: unexpected ',' in "hp_wt <-c(for(i,"
> f<- for (i in data) {data$hp/data$wt}
> f
NULL
> for (i in data) {data$hp/data$wt}
> f<- c(for (i in data) {data$hp/data$wt})
> f
NULL
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Columns in R `data.frames` can easily be divided like this:

```
data$hp / data$wt
```

Furthermore, you can assign the resulting vector to a new column:

```
data$hp_wt <- data$hp / data$wt
```

Thus, you don't need to loop over all rows.

Comment: Thank you, your response helped me understand the basic structure of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Loki's way is the right one to solve your problem in practice.

But if you really insist on using for loop, then:

```
powerToWeight <- NULL
temp <- NULL
# for each row in the dataset
for (i in 1:nrow(data))
{
    # calculate hp/wt ratio for a given observation
    temp <- as.numeric(data[i, "hp"])/as.numeric(data[i, "wt"])
    # attach the ratio to previously calculated values
    powerToWeight <- c(powerToWeight, temp)
}

# attach the calculated vector to the original dataset
data$hpToWt <- powerToWeight
```

... is one of the ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful and it appears to be a simple loop: it is perfect for a beginner like me.

Comment: In R, the basic data structure is the vector. Even scalar variables are vectors of length 1. Therefore, many operations are vectorized. If you want to learn R, start to think in vectors and vector operations not in for loops.

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly agree with @loki that you don't need to write a `for` loop in R to divide two vectors or columns of a data frame, the OP asked explicetly for a solution using a `for` loop. So, here is one:

```
hp_wt <- numeric(0)
for (i in seq.int(nrow(data))) {
  hp_wt[i] <- with(data[i, ], hp / wt)
}
```

However, the following benchmark shows that this is not a very good idea w.r.t. performance:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  vector = data$hp / data$wt,
  for_loop = {
    hp_wt <- numeric(0)
    for (i in seq.int(nrow(data))) {
      hp_wt[i] <- with(data[i, ], hp / wt)
    }
  }
)

Unit: microseconds
     expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval
   vector   9.817  10.573  13.34426  11.706  12.461   47.954   100
 for_loop 431.576 463.292 496.04711 469.333 494.442 1723.656   100
```

The `for` loop in R is about 40 times slower than the vector computation.

Comment: Thank you, your response is helpful.